# How to mimic GROUP BY in Cassandra

Tags: sql, cassandra

Is it possible to mimic GROUP BY functionality from SQL using Cassandra? If yes, please provide a short example that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking, if the groups where known a head of time, then a loop of multiple async queries on each different group would have a similar effect.

For example group by on months.

```
for month in range(1,12):
    query = "select * from table where col_month = " + month
    session.execute_async(query)
```

If this isn't an option you would have to first select what you are grouping on and take the set of all data.

```
query = "select col_month from table"
rows = session.execute(query) 
values = Set()
for row in rows:
    values.add(row)

query = "select * from table where col_month = "
for value in values:
    session.execute_async(query+value)
```